# Calculating Bearing in SQL "An invalid floating point operation occurred."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been fighting with this issue all day. I realize that an

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

error is a result of something being out of bounds but for the life of me I'm struggling to find my issue in the bearing formula below.

```
CAST((DEGREES(ROUND(ATN2(SIN(Radians(dest.longitude - orig.longitude))*COS(Radians(dest.latitude)),COS(Radians(orig.latitude))*SIN(Radians(dest.latitude))-SIN(Radians(orig.latitude))*COS(Radians(dest.latitude))*COS(Radians(dest.longitude - orig.longitude))),2)) + 360) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) % 360
```

Does anybody have any recommendations for rounding/conversions to remedy this? It has run successfully in the past but is struggling with my new data.

I have gone through [this post on the issue here](http://forums.sqlteam.com/t/t-sql-error-msg-3623-invalid-floating-point/4935) without much success.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

After a thorough breakdown it appears that some of my origin & destination locations are the same latitude & longitude (because we're drawing them from zip-codes, something we plan to fix) causing an **ATN2(0,0)** calculation leading to the floating point operation error.

...It's the simple stupid things that make us waste half a day.

Comment: What values did it fail on?

Comment: I wish I knew, it's going through 467 lines. It's succeeding on
 LAWRENCE KS 38.884269 -95.348463 CHESAPEAKE VA 36.643075 -76.278472 though.

It gives me a bearing of 92.24621. That's 90 degrees from North: so it's East.

Comment: I would start by writing another query in which you break the entire calculation out into its smaller parts in separate columns. Then you can get a better sense of what is contributing to the problem. Because the tangent function (and likewise arc-tangent) is a ratio, there could be division by zero issues happening somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Pat. That's probably the best choice. I'll work on that and update tomorrow when i see what's going on.